# how to make my master page relevant to all my subsites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page

I applicate the master page to the parent site and to all my subsites.
In fact the master page was not applicated to all the subsite.
this is the hierarchy:

```
-parent site: type publishing  -sub site1: wikisite
                               -subsite 2:team site 
                               -subsite 3: publishing
```

I only found the subsite 3 have the same master page as parent site?
So is teher a solution how to force all the subsite to take the parent's master page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is. Either by C#:

```
var web = SPContext.Current.Web; //you can get that in a different way
var rootWeb = web.Site.RootWeb; //You root web site
web.MasterUrl = rootWeb.MasterUrl;
web.CustomMasterUrl = rootWeb.CustomMasterUrl;
web.Update();
```

or by PowerShell:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://wikisiteURL
$rootWeb = Get-SPWeb http://parentsiteURL
$web.MasterUrl = $rootWeb.MasterUrl;
$web.CustomMasterUrl = $root.CustomMasterUrl;
$web.Update();
```

Throw in a `for-each` for `web.Site.AllWebs` and you will be able to do that for all the subsites. Don't forget to properly dispose of the `SPWeb` objects as well.

Comment: $rootWeb = Get-SPWeb $web.ParentWeb.Url a have erroe on this , and $rootWeb.MasterUrl= give the seattle

Comment: Use this instead: $rootWeb = Get-SPWeb $web.Site.RootWeb; and then $rootWeb.MasterUrl should display your custom master page.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped a bit of code. This is how it needs to look like: $rootWeb = $web.Site.RootWeb; Your code should work. Does it give any error?

Comment: know ok , it works fine